# Rating documents with Lucene

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval, rating

## Rating documents with Lucene

I am new to Lucene, I am going to rate some documents with tf-idf algorithm. My documents have these fields :

> I, T, A, B, W

My `index` function :

```
private void indexFile(File f) throws Exception {
   Document doc = getDocument(f);
   writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

My `getDocument` function:

```
protected Document getDocument(File f) throws Exception {

    String content = fileReader(f.getPath());

    ...

    Document doc = new Document();

    doc.add(new StringField("I", content.substring(I + 3, T - 1), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("T", content.substring(T + 3, A - 1), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("A", content.substring(A + 3, B - 1), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("B", content.substring(B + 3, W - 1), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("W", content.substring(W + 3, content.length() - 1), Field.Store.YES));

    return doc;
}
```

And my `search` function:

```
public void search(int queryNumber, String q) throws IOException, ParseException {
        IndexReader rdr = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIRECTORY)));
        IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(rdr);

        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("W", new StandardAnalyzer());
        parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);

        Query query = parser.parse(q);

        TopDocs hits = is.search(query, 20);

        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
            Document doc = is.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
            System.out.println(queryNumber + " " + doc.get("I"));
        }
    }
```

The problem is my search function which always return 0 hit doc for all queries. Where is my fault?

My other question is "How can I change and modify the `tf-idf` algorithm?

Comment: `StringField` is not analyzed. If your fields should be analyzed, use `TextField` instead.

Comment: yes, finally i use this line of code instead and the problem solved

 
`````doc.add(new TextField("W", new FileReader(f)));`````


my second part of question, i am going to change the rating algorithm and use another one, how can i do this?
@femtoRgon